# Redmin issue with creating new issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redmine, redmine-api

I am trying to create new issue on redmine but on browser it "show me internal server error".

I have checked the logs it showed me the following logs error,

"
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 48ms (ActiveRecord: 2.5ms)

NoMethodError (undefined method `first_response_date' for #<Issue:0x007fc60ab0fe78>):
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in`block (2 levels) in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in `each'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:61:in`block in call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in `tap'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:58:in`call_hook'
  lib/redmine/hook.rb:162:in `call_hook'
  app/controllers/issues_controller.rb:139:in`create'

"
I am quite new to ruby on rail please help me how i resolve this issue.
Thanks

Comment: Do you use any plugins? What a plugin you plugged last?

Comment: It's definitely plugin issue. Show us full trace  and list of plugins.